# No transaction is currently active

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, desktop-application

so i have this code here

```
User us = new User();
            us.setId(id1);
            us.setUsername(userNameTextField.getText());
            us.setPassowrd(passwordFormattedTextField.getText());
            us.setLevel(levelComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
            us.setEmpid(getCurrentEmp());
            getCurrentEmp().getUserCollection().add(us);
            em.getTransaction().begin();               
            em.persist(getCurrentEmp());
            em.flush();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
```

but when i try to commit i get this error

```
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.throwCheckTransactionFailedException(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:87)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.checkForTransaction(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:50)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.checkForTransaction(EntityManagerImpl.java:2015)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:846)
```

and i dont get y since i have called the entitymanager instance as follows

```
em = emi.getInstance();
```

from this class

```
public class EmInstance {
EntityManager em;
public EntityManager getInstance(){
em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("samplePU").createEntityManager();
return em;
}
```

}

My question is how can i make the transaction active whenever i want to use it e.i when committing,updating or any other transaction process. Am using eclipselink and its a desktop application

Comment: What version of eclipselink are you using, and can you try the a latest if you aren't already?

Comment: The exception is caused by a flush which might be an implicit flush triggered by the persistence provider; you might want to try moving that getTransaction().begin() to the beginning of the method to make sure that a transaction is active anywhere JPA might be involved.

Comment: if you are using contaner managed transaction then @Transactional annotaion of spring will work in your menthod. If you are using REOURCE_LOCAL type then you need to begin and commit the transaction programatically.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that calling `em.getTransaction()` those two times gives you back the same transaction?
Try with:

```
EntityTransaction etx = em.getTransaction();
etx.begin();
...
etx.commit();
```